# User draw a polygon on a Resium map

Tags: polygon-creation, cesium, react

Does anyone have an idea of how you could allow the user to draw a polygon on a resium map?

Resium is a react library using cesium. I have an app that has entities placed on the map and I'd like to allow the user to select an area on the map by drawing a polygon using their mouse and be able to filter out entities not in the polygon the user created.